# my app keeps crashes when i move to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class XOGame extends Activity {

    Button btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btn9;
    boolean btnFlag,theEnd;
    private final static int RESTART = Menu.FIRST;
    private final static int GO_BACK_TO_CHAT = Menu.FIRST+1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_xogame);

        btnFlag = true;
        theEnd = false;
        btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        btn2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
        btn3 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
        btn4 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b4);
        btn5 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b5);
        btn6 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b6);
        btn7 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b7);
        btn8 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b8);
        btn9 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.b9);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(btn1.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    if(btnFlag == true){
                        btnFlag = false;
                        btn1.setText("X");
                    }
                    else if(btnFlag == false)
                    {
                        btnFlag = true;
                        btn1.setText("O");
                    }
                }
                GameIsOver();

            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(btn2.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    if(btnFlag == true){
                        btnFlag = false;
                        btn2.setText("X");
                    }
                    else if(btnFlag == false)
                    {
                        btnFlag = true;
                        btn2.setText("O");
                    }
                }
                GameIsOver();
            }
        });

        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(btn3.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    if(btnFlag == true){
                        btnFlag = false;
                        btn3.setText("X");
                    }
                    else if(btnFlag == false)
                    {
                        btnFlag = true;
                        btn3.setText("O");
                    }
                }
                GameIsOver();
            }
        });

        btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(btn4.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    if(btnFlag == true){
                        btnFlag = false;
                        btn4.setText("X");
                    }
                    else if(btnFlag == false)
                    {
                        btnFlag = true;
                        btn4.setText("O");
                    }
                }
                GameIsOver();
            }
        });

        btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(btn5.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    if(btnFlag == true){
                        btnFlag = false;
                        btn5.setText("X");
                    }
                    else if(btnFlag == false)
                    {
                        btnFlag = true;
                        btn5.setText("O");
                    }
                }
                GameIsOver();
            }
        });

        btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(btn6.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    if(btnFlag == true){
                        btnFlag = false;
                        btn6.setText("X");
                    }
                    else if(btnFlag == false)
                    {
                        btnFlag = true;
                        btn6.setText("O");
                    }
                }
                GameIsOver();
            }
        });

        btn7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(btn7.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    if(btnFlag == true){
                        btnFlag = false;
                        btn7.setText("X");
                    }
                    else if(btnFlag == false)
                    {
                        btnFlag = true;
                        btn7.setText("O");
                    }
                    GameIsOver();
                }
            }
        });

        btn8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(btn8.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    if(btnFlag == true){
                        btnFlag = false;
                        btn8.setText("X");
                    }
                    else if(btnFlag == false)
                    {
                        btnFlag = true;
                        btn8.setText("O");
                    }
                    GameIsOver();
                }
            }
        });

        btn9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(btn9.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    if(btnFlag == true){
                        btnFlag = false;
                        btn9.setText("X");
                    }
                    else if(btnFlag == false)
                    {
                        btnFlag = true;
                        btn9.setText("O");
                    }
                }
                GameIsOver();
            }
        });


    }


    public void GameIsOver(){
        String btn11,btn22,btn33,btn44,btn55,btn66,btn77,btn88,btn99;
        btn11 = btn1.getText().toString();
        btn22 = btn2.getText().toString();
        btn33 = btn3.getText().toString();
        btn44 = btn4.getText().toString();
        btn55 = btn5.getText().toString();
        btn66 = btn6.getText().toString();
        btn77 = btn7.getText().toString();
        btn88 = btn8.getText().toString();
        btn99 = btn9.getText().toString();

        if(btn11.equals("X")&&btn22.equals("X")&&btn33.equals("X")){
            Toast.makeText(XOGame.this,R.string.congrats_x_wins,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            theEnd = true;
        }
        if(btn11.equals("X")&&btn55.equals("X")&&btn99.equals("X")){
            Toast.makeText(XOGame.this,R.string.congrats_x_wins,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            theEnd = true;
        }
        if(btn11.equals("X")&&btn44.equals("X")&&btn77.equals("X")){
            Toast.makeText(XOGame.this,R.string.congrats_x_wins,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            theEnd = true;
        }
        if(btn22.equals("X")&&btn55.equals("X")&&btn88.equals("X")){
            Toast.makeText(XOGame.this,R.string.congrats_x_wins,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            theEnd = true;
        }
        if(btn33.equals("X")&&btn66.equals("X")&&btn99.equals("X")){
            Toast.makeText(XOGame.this,R.string.congrats_x_wins,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            theEnd = true;
        }
        if(btn44.equals("X")&&btn55.equals("X")&&btn66.equals("X")){
            Toast.makeText(XOGame.this,R.string.congrats_x_wins,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            theEnd = true;
        }
        if(btn55.equals("X")&&btn33.equals("X")&&btn77.equals("X")){
            Toast.makeText(XOGame.this,R.string.congrats_x_wins,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            theEnd = true;
        }
        if(btn77.equals("X")&&btn88.equals("X")&&btn99.equals("X")){
            Toast.makeText(XOGame.this,R.string.congrats_x_wins,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            theEnd = true;
        }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if(btn11.equals("O")&&btn22.equals("O")&&btn33.equals("O")){
            Toast.makeText(XOGame.this,R.string.congrats_o_wins,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            theEnd = true;
        }
        if(btn11.equals("O")&&btn55.equals("O")&&btn99.equals("O")){
            Toast.makeText(XOGame.this,R.string.congrats_o_wins,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            theEnd = true;
        }
        if(btn11.equals("O")&&btn44.equals("O")&&btn77.equals("O")){
            Toast.makeText(XOGame.this,R.string.congrats_o_wins,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            theEnd = true;
        }
        if(btn22.equals("O")&&btn55.equals("O")&&btn88.equals("O")){
            Toast.makeText(XOGame.this,R.string.congrats_o_wins,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            theEnd = true;
        }
        if(btn33.equals("O")&&btn66.equals("O")&&btn99.equals("O")){
            Toast.makeText(XOGame.this,R.string.congrats_o_wins,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            theEnd = true;
        }
        if(btn44.equals("O")&&btn55.equals("O")&&btn66.equals("O")){
            Toast.makeText(XOGame.this,R.string.congrats_o_wins,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            theEnd = true;
        }
        if(btn55.equals("O")&&btn33.equals("O")&&btn77.equals("O")){
            Toast.makeText(XOGame.this,R.string.congrats_o_wins,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            theEnd = true;
        }
        if(btn77.equals("O")&&btn88.equals("O")&&btn99.equals("O")){
            Toast.makeText(XOGame.this,R.string.congrats_o_wins,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            theEnd = true;
        }

        if(theEnd == true) {
            btn1.setClickable(false);
            btn2.setClickable(false);
            btn3.setClickable(false);
            btn4.setClickable(false);
            btn5.setClickable(false);
            btn6.setClickable(false);
            btn7.setClickable(false);
            btn8.setClickable(false);
            btn9.setClickable(false);
        }

    }
```

when i click on the menu that takes me to another activity the app crashes
        // adding the menu for the xo game

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        //adding menu options
        menu.add(0, RESTART, 0, R.string.restart);
        menu.add(0, GO_BACK_TO_CHAT, 0, R.string.go_back_to_chat);
        return result;
    }
```

i tried 2 diffrient cases but it didnot work 
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item)
        {

```
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case RESTART:
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(XOGame.this, XOGame.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }
            /*  case GO_BACK_TO_CHAT:
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(XOGame.this, WritingMessage.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }*/
            /*case GO_BACK_TO_CHAT:
            {
                XOGame.this.finish();
                return true;
            }*/
        }

        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind adding your error message? :)

Comment: Your activities are declared in the AndroidManifest !?

Comment: their is no an error message it only crashes

Comment: @sharbel if you are using eclipse check the log cat, in other case check the debugger or something like this

Comment: You need to provide your logcat log when you have errors. But i think i saw what is the problem: Intent i = new Intent(XOGame.this, XOGame.class); first parameter should be current activity, not the one you want to start

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by finishing the intent after restart the intent.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you are setting text in a background thread, when it really needs to be done on the main/UI thread. The OnButtonPressed spawns a new thread, and if you need to update any UI you need to do something like below.

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         btn1.setText("some text");
    }
}
```

Same needs to be done with a toast if it's done in a background thread.